# Perfectly Imperfect Bash Script Can't Pass Variable to Renice Command

Tags: linux, bash, nice

I have written a bash script that is 100% correct according to `https://www.shellcheck.net/#`.  The code should renice, then cpulimit any desired applications and their relative pids.

```
#!/bin/bash
INTERVAL=10
PROCESSES_TO_WATCH=gnome-shell
set -x

while sleep $INTERVAL; do
        for process_name in $PROCESSES_TO_WATCH; do
        pid_list=("$(pgrep "$process_name")")

        # Don't do anything if no running process found
        [ ${#pid_list[@]} -le 0 ] && continue

                for pid in "${pid_list[@]}"; do
                renice -n 19 -p "$pid" && cpulimit -p "$pid" -l 20  

                done
        done
done
#EOF
```

**Problem:**
The output shows that renice command is rejecting the "$pid" variable values:

```
+ sleep 10
+ for process_name in $PROCESSES_TO_WATCH
+ pid_list=("$(pgrep "$process_name")")
++ pgrep gnome-shell
+ '[' 1 -le 0 ']'
+ for pid in "${pid_list[@]}"
+ renice -n 19 -p '1797
3709
3074206'
renice: bad process ID value: 1797
3709
3074206
```

**Progress**
The solution seems to be *use an **incorrect** script*

I changed `renice -n 19 -p "$pid" && cpulimit -p "$pid" -l 20` to  `renice -n 19 -p $pid && cpulimit -p $pid -l 20`

And now the output shows it works as designed:

```
root@machine# /usr/local/bin/process-leash.sh 
+ sleep 10
+ for process_name in $PROCESSES_TO_WATCH
+ pid_list=("$(pgrep "$process_name")")
++ pgrep gnome-shell
+ '[' 1 -le 0 ']'
+ for pid in "${pid_list[@]}"
+ renice -n 19 -p 1797 3709 3074206
1797 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
3709 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
3074206 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
+ cpulimit -p 1797 3709 3074206 -l 20
Process 1797 detected
```

Meanwhile `https://www.shellcheck.net/#` is screaming its head off

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 14:
                renice -n 19 -p $pid && cpulimit -p $pid -l 20  
                                ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                                    ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
                renice -n 19 -p "$pid" && cpulimit -p "$pid" -l 20
```

Any ideas why the quotes on the variables caused this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shellcheck doesn't know what you *meant*, so its generic "Double quote to prevent word-splitting" advice is actually working against you. The output of `pgrep "$process_name"` returns a space-separated list of PIDs, which *needs* to be word-split when you're assigning it to an array, but because you've double-quoted the value during assignment it always remains a single string.

Comment: It's not the whole story. The version that worked for the OP still assigns a double-quoted string to the array, the array has one element, the `for pid in "${pid_list[@]}"` loop executes once, finally `$pid` gets split when `renice` or `cpulimit` is called. This means the loop is not needed. Unless maybe there were so many PIDs so `argument list too long` would occur. In such case an array is a good idea, but then the quotes should be dropped at the assignment to the array, not later.

Comment: That works for renice, which has `-p` as a boolean flag and takes a list of PIDs as unrelated positional args (meaning you can specify any amount), but cpulimit is a different case because the PID is instead specified as an `-p` parameter – so if word-splitting is done at this point, only the first PID is accepted as the -p parameter, while the rest become positional args and are ignored (although in the version I have it rejects them with an error message).